# How to debug external plugin in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, plugins, rcp

I have a question regarding debuging an Eclipse plugin in production (Hibernate Tools).

I downloaded the source package from JBoss repo, but I am unable to view `org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter` source code and add a breakpoint.

I am just running a normal Java EE instance of Eclipse.

Is it possible to do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the plugin into your workspace :

```
Right click on explorer > Import ... > Plugin and fragments
```

then, on first page :

```
**Import From :** The active target platform
**Plugins and Fragments to Import :** Select from all plugins...
**Import As :** Project with source folder
```

On the second page :

```
Double click on the plugin wanted (probably org.hibernate.*)
```

Then finish, the plugin should be available as source for debugging in your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

The steps are descibed quite well here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13330393/4916630

Install plugins only or download the complete JBoss Developer Studio (Luna) from here: http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/devstudio/luna/8.1.0.GA.html#marketplace

Now you will have plugin working in the IDE.

To remote debug your plug-in, first add debug arguments to your target Eclipse .ini file

```
-vmargs
-Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044
```

before launching it.

Then open another Eclipse instance with a workspace containing your plug-in project (here only source of the plugin is needed). Open Run > Debug Configurations..., select Remote Java Application and create a new configuration.

As Project, browse and select your plug-in project. Also fill in your connection properties (host of target Eclipse and port 1044).

Launching the newly created debug configuration allows you to debug your plug-in the same way you debug locally.

Comment: The only problem i have is that it is not my own plug-in project, and it just doesn't work in my current workspace (i am working in).