# Debugging eclipse with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jvm, remote-access

I would like to debug an Eclipse view available in latest Neon release. I found class responsible for view's behavior via plugin-inspector (ALT+SHIFT+F1 on mouseover). I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324722/debugging-eclipse-plug-ins) question (and some similar articles too) to debug one eclipse instance with another.

I did following steps:

1. I launch an eclipse instance which I want to debug
2. I launch another eclipse instance
3. I open Debug Configurations view
4. I create new Remote Java Application configuration fill host with 'localhost' and port with '1044'
5. I click debug and then I get an error "Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused. Connection refused:connect"

What am I doing wrong?

Additions:

eclipse.ini in step 1

```
-vm
I:/prep_ide_win_test/Tools/jre/jre/bin/javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.400.v20160518-1444
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.rcp.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

eclipse.ini in step 2

```
-vm
I:/prep_ide_win_test/Tools/jre/jre/bin/javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.400.v20160518-1444
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.rcp.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

Launching my debug configuration
[image: dbg conf]

An error

[image: error]

//Edit: I am looking for functionality of this button in Eclipse welcome screen:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new **Eclipse Application** configuration instead, then Debug that.

Comment: Sorry for late response. This sadly does not launch exact Eclipse as the installed one. To be more specific I want to look at implementation of "Review IDE configuration settings" option on welcome screen, which is not present if i launch empty project as empty application. /See edits in original answer.

Comment: All right I managed how to launch exactly same eclipse instance as running.  I have created Eclipse Application configuration in which in Run a product: selection I had to select org.eclipse.epp.package.rcp.product (in my case) instead of just org.eclipse.platform.ide. Thanks.